# @KafkaListener with topicPattern and consumer group name based on the topic assigned

Tags: spring-kafka

I would like to use  @KafkaListener and base the consumer group on the name of the topic
attached but using a topic pattern.

Example with a single topic

```
@KafkaListener(
        id = "test",
        topic=  "tenant15",
        groupId = "my_group_tenant15")
```

I would like to generalize this with a topicPattern (tenant*) instead of static topic

Any idea how to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done; the group is needed when creating the consumer whereas the topic(s) matching the pattern will be assigned later.